# Constrain UITableViewCell so height and width change with device rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using the **"storyboard"** with `autolayout` on and I want to achieve the following effect:

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXbCU.jpg)

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg5aU.jpg)

I had this working with constraints when I used buttons but with **custom cells** they seem to refuse to resize.

Comment: You should be able to do this with auto layout. Did you try sending different height for cell using table view delegate method - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
try to to send different height depending on the device orientation

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting UITextField objects to resize on rotation when the constraints were relative to the other objects.

When I made the constraints relative to the superview it worked fine.